# AngularJS ngRoute url redirection

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have this simple AngularJS app using ngRoute:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
    })
    .when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }
]);
```

I'm doing oAuth in which I direct a user to another site for authentication and once they're authenticated, they will be redirected to the redirect url I provided with the client token appended. For example: `http://example.com#client_token=CLIENT_TOKEN`

Because I'm using ngRoute, whenever I visit `http://example.com`, the url will become `http://example.com/#/` so I can't get the client token from the url.

I've tried setting it to:

1. `http://example.com` but got redirected to `http://example.com/#/`. Which is missing `client_token=CLIENT_TOKEN`
2. `http://example.com/#/profile` but got redirected to `http://example.com/#` as well.

But when I visit `http://example.com/#/profile#test=abcd` directly, it's fine.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: normally your token url would be `http://example.com?client_token=CLIENT_TOKEN` to avoid this sort of issue.  Angular (and most other SPA frameworks) treat `#` uniquely, as does the browser.  Technically, the URL you are trying to use is malformed.

Comment: I'm using the Instagram Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication API so there's nothing I can change https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: well then either your Instagram API is messed up or you mistyped something, because the example URL in the link you posted in your comment *definitely* is using `?` and not `#`.

Comment: Look at the last one under `Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication API`

Comment: yeah, I just noticed that, it's abnormal.  I'm not sure if you can use that kind of response.  You can try turning on `html5Mode` in angular, but I suspect you will still have issues.

Comment: I'm suspecting it might be the way `#` is handled when doing redirection. When I authenticate the user, I have to encode `#` to `%23` in `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token`